# Efficient computation of the minimum distance of a binary linear code

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity, coding-theory

I need to find parameters $n$, $k$ and $d$ of a binary linear code from its Generator Matrix.

How can I find parameter $d$ efficiently?

I know the method that compute all the codewords and take minimum non-zero weight code will be the minimum distance. but it's an exponential time algorithm. Is there any efficient algorithm to do the same?

Comment: In general, I think not. In particular examples, there is often some trick available.

Comment: this seems to be a web page to compute it, see [bounds on minimum distance of linear codes](https://www.iks.kit.edu/home/grassl/codetables/BKLC/BKLC_query.php) by Grassl

Comment: @vzn: The homepage of Grassl (which I also linked in my answer) is for collecting the best known minimum distances of linear codes of fixed length and dimension. In most of the cases, also generator matrices of those codes are provided. But as far as I see, the page doesn't provide means for the computation of the minimum distance of an arbitrary linear code.

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out by Snowball, the problem is inherently hard, see [here](https://doi.org/10.1109/18.641542) and also [here](https://doi.org/10.1145/258533.258559).

However, it can be done much faster in general than generating all the codewords. The best practical method known is the Brouwer-Zimmermann algorithm.

I explain the idea for linear $[n,k]$ codes $C$ with $n = 2k$.
First, we construct two generator matrices $G_1 = (I\mid A)$ and $G_2 = (B\mid I)$ of $C$ where $I$ is the $(k\times k)$ unit matrix and $A,B$ are two $(k\times k)$ matrices. This is only possible if the positions $1,\ldots,k$ and $k+1,\ldots n$ form two information sets of $C$. If this is not the case, we have to find a suitable coordinate permutation first.

Now a codeword of weight $w$ has weight at most $\lfloor w/2\rfloor$ either in the first or in the second $n$ coordinates.
Thus, we can find all codewords of weight $\leq w$ among the codewords $x G_1 = (x \mid xA)$ and $x G_2 = (Bx \mid x)$, where $x$ is a vector of length $k$ and Hamming weight at most $\lfloor w/2\rfloor$.
So we can find the minimum distance $d$ of $C$ if we do this iteratively for all $w = 1,2,3,\ldots, d$.

In this way, you have to generate only a small fraction of all the codewords to find the minimum distance, and the idea can be generalized to any linear code. The first step then is to find a covering of the coordinates with information sets. However, the algorithm is still exponential, of course.

To my knowledge, the algorithm has been discovered by Andries Brouwer for self-dual codes (where we are in the case $n = 2k$ and moreover, by self-duality we can take $B = -A^\top$) and generalized by Karl-Heinz Zimmermann to general linear codes. The earliest published source of this algorithm I'm aware of is on pages 30–33 in the (German) book

Anton Betten, Harald Fripertinger, Adalbert Kerber, Alfred Wassermann, Karl-Heinz Zimmermann: Codierungstheorie: Konstruktion und Anwendung linearer Codes, Spinger, 1998, ISBN 3-540-64502-0, [link](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-58973-7)

A few more comments:

- All non-zero scalar multiples of a codeword have the same weight and thus, it is enough to touch a single representative in the enumeration. For $q$-ary linear codes, this is a speedup by the factor $q-1$ (and hence only relevant for non-binary linear codes).
- If the investigated code has nontrivial automorphisms (for instance cyclic codes), these may be used to further reduce the number of codewords in the enumeration.
- If the code $C$ has large dimension, such that the dimension of $C^\perp$ is small, it might be better not to use the Brouwer-Zimmermann algorithm. Instead, enumerate all codewords of $C^\perp$ to determine the weight enumerator of $C^\perp$ and apply the MacWilliams identitites to get the weight enumerator (and in particular the minimum distance) of $C$.
- The webpage [codetables.de](http://codetables.de/) is a valuable source for bounds on the best known minimum distances for fixed $q$, $n$ and $k$.

Comment: the paper seems to be by Vardy based on url but is not accessible [maybe not a eprint available]. another published citation would be ideal. maybe this ref? (found in another paper) Alexander Vardy. The intractability of computing the minimum distance of a code. IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory, 43(6):1757–1766, 1997.

Comment: @vzn: Looks like the link is dead. Yes, it is the 1997 Vardy paper. I've updated the link to the IEEE homepage.

Answer (score 10):

Finding the minimum distance $d$ of a linear code is equivalent to finding its minimum weight. According to [*On the inherent intractability of certain coding problems*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1978.1055873), given the check matrix, determining whether or not there exists a codeword of some fixed weight $w$ is a NP-complete problem for binary linear codes.

As Gerry commented, you can easily find the minimum distance for particular codes. For example:

1. If you have a Reed-Solomon code of length $n$ and dimension $k$, its minimum distance is $n-k+1$.
2. If you have a Hamming code, its minimum distance is $3$.