# Generator Polynomial and Minimum Distance

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, coding-theory

Given a generator polynomial, how do I calculate minimum distance for the code. I am working in GF(2).

A particular case of interest is the cyclic code of length $9$ generated by
$$
g(x)=x^7+x^6+x^4+x^3+x+1.
$$

Comment: If I figured out an efficient way of calculating this in the general case, I would be a famous coding theorist professor instead of a mediocre ex-researcher and a grumpy calculus lecturer. IOW, to the best of my knowledge no efficient general method is known. So I really doubt that you have been asked to solve this. Please give some context! Are you working on a special case? How/where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: I have found all generating polynomials for all cyclic codes of length 7 and 9 over GF(2). I need to find the dmin for each cyclic code.

Comment: Ok. Glad to hear that you don't want this worked out for codes of length 65535 or thereabouts :-) What tools have been covered? BCH-bound? Some (many?) of the codes that you get are relatively small, say at most 16 codewords, so that you can brute force those. For some you can use BCH-bound to get a lower bound to the minimum distance, and then finding one word of that weight within the code settles the question. Which generator polynomials are giving you a headache?

Comment: It seems to me that your question has attracted a vote to put it on hold. The style of asking a question that looks like a homework problem without showing your own work is frowned upon here. I recommend that you work out at least one example in the question body. That should prevent the question from creating unpleasant feelings. For example, what's the minimum distance of the code of length seven generated by $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$? :-)

Comment: And welcome to Math.SE. The previous comment is about how the site works. We will help people struggling with HW problems - no problem there. But the approach is that of "teach a man how to fish" as opposed to "do my work for me" :-)

Comment: Here is one generating polynomial - x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1.

Comment: Ok, so that generates a code of length 9. Your polynomial, call it $g(x)$, is a factor of $x^9+1$, so you did that step correctly! The codewords are all polynomials of degree $\le 8$. That means that the words of the code are of the form $g(x)a(x)$, where $a(x)$ is restricted to being a polynomial of degree $\le1$. Therefore there are only four choices for $a(x)$, namely $a(x)\in\{0,1,x,x+1\}$. Surely you can relatively quickly calculate all those 4 products, and spot the one with minimal weight!

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: To an extent I disagree with the judgement of the members who put this question on hold. Yes, I agree that the OP should have showed some effort in question body, e.g. by listing the troublesome generator polynomials. Yet, the comments revealed that a non-significant amount background work had been done. Do add an example case or something, and will vote to reopen! As it is I don't want to overrule people I respect (largely because I'm biased in favor of having more coding-theoretical questions, and cannot ignore that bias while judging).

Comment: Another is x^3 + 1. Now a(x) is restricted to degree <= 5 which gives a lot of choices. Do I have to list all codewords and then calculate minimal weight or is there a better method?

Comment: Yes. You do have a lot of choices for $a(x)$ in that case. However, your generator is already a word of weight two. And no multiple of it can be of weight one, so... :-)

Comment: So with a generator or high degree there are less choices and for a generator with low degree we can multiply the generator by 1 and essentially the number of terms in this generator is the dmin. Does this sound correct? Thanks

Comment: Not always exactly that way, but not too far off for short codes. When the generator has weight $\le 3$, it always is the lowest weight word (because $x^n+1$ is the lowest degree binomial divisible by $g(x)$). If the generator has a higher weight, then it isn't so clear. That's where BCH-bound becomes useful (it gives a lower bound to the minimum distance). In general it is very tricky, and there are reasonably short cyclic codes (length a couple hundred or so) whose minimum distance is unknown.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Can you help me with my alpha^2 question on primitive polynomials?

Comment: Is Leox's answer at the bottom correct?

Comment: Sure. It is correct. But if the dimension of the code is even relatively moderate, then doing it that way will take a while. I once wrote a computer program to do that for me in the case of a code with $2^{32}\approx 4\cdot 10^9$ words, because I wanted to know how many words of any given weight there were. The program ran over night (this was in the DOS-era) and gave me the answer I needed in the morning :-)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up figuring out the parity-check matrix from the generator matrix and then used the number of columns of the parity-check matrix to get the dmin.

Answer (score 1):

For general cyclic codes, no efficient way is known to compute the minimum distance. For example, the exact minimum distances of the binary quadratic residue code of lengths > 200 (certain cyclic codes) are not known.

You can apply various bounds (in particular, the BCH bound) to get a rough idea about the value, which may be enough to pin down the minimum distance for small cases. But in general, no better approach is known than enumerating an exponential number of codewords. I've sketched the best known method for general linear codes in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362039/61691).

Answer (score 1):

Any cyclic code is a linear code. So you may find the minimum distance by the following algorithm

1. Find all code polynomials  for this code.
2. Calculate a number of terms for each code polynomial.
3. The minimal number of terms be exactly the minimum distance.