# Maximum-weight codeword in a linear code

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, optimization, finite-fields, coding-theory

I was dealing with an optimization problem, that happens to be equivalent to finding a max-weight codeword in a linear code, over $\mathbb{F}_2$. In other words, $A$ being the parity-check matrix, and $w(x)$ the Hamming weight of $x$, the problem is $$\max w(x), \text{ s. t. } Ax = 0 \mod 2.$$
I know this problem is NP-Hard but I wondered if it had a specific name, because searching the literature only leads me to the *maximum-likelihood decoding problem*, which is a more general case, and the methods do not apply to prohibitively large dimensions (here, I deal with a code of length 1000 and dimension 300, which is a very big instance...)

I use the following heuristic to solve it, but I think it could be improved:

I build the parity-check matrix $(A | I_{700})$ (coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$), where $A$ is a matrix $700 \times 300$ and since my solution space is its null space, I try to find the largest column set that sums to $0$. To do so, I randomly select a subset $S$ of the columns of $A$. Summing these columns gives a vector $v$. For each component $1 \leq i \leq 700$ such that $v_i = 1$, I add the column $e_i$ ($i$-th 'unit' vector) to the column set. In other words, I use the convenient fact that I have unit vectors in the parity-check matrix to ensure that the final set of columns sums to 0. This operation is repeated and the best set is recorded. This method gives really good solutions if it runs long enough, but relies too much on randomness, and there must be better ideas. (Linear Programming is really bad for this problem, especially for large sizes, unfortunately)

If anyone has ever studied this problem or a similar one, please feel free to give me some references that might be useful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Given binary matrix $A$, you want to find binary vector $x$ and integer vector $y$ to minimize $\sum_j x_j$ subject to $Ax=2y$? Are you able to share your $A$ matrix?

Comment: That's it, but I want to maximize instead of minimize. I could share the matrix, it's pretty big (700 rows, 1000 columns), I sparsified it to ~93000 ones (out of 700000). I don't know if it's possible to upload files here

Comment: If you put a link to the data, I’ll give it a try.

Comment: What's the largest $w(x)$ you found so far?

Comment: 739, found using the iterative method described in my post. Integer Programming performs poorly on this problem, mainly because of modulo constraints. Some formulations are better than the classical one, but have too many binaries (over 6 millions for this one...) Because of that, I have no reliable optimality gap with my solution, but I suppose it's very good, though i'm almost sure it's not optimal.

Comment: The best I got with ILP in a reasonable time is 683, with a very weak upper bound close to 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few words on the computation of the maximum weight:

For practical purposes, the Brouwer-Zimmermann algorithm is the best known algorithm for the computation of the *minimum* weight of a linear code. It can be adapted in an obvious way to compute the maximum weight. See my description of the algorithm in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362039/61691).

I guess your parameters (length $n = 1000$) will be too large for the algorithm to terminate within a reasonable amount of time unless the maximum weight is very close to $n$. It still might make sense to run the algorithm, since at any point it gives you a lower and upper bound on the maximum weight, which subsequently get sharpened until they coincide.

**Addition**

I have another idea, which might or might not help in your situation. If you augment the code $C$ by the all-1-vector $\boldsymbol 1$ to a linear code $C'$ (such that $\operatorname{dim} C' = \operatorname{dim} C + 1$), for each original codeword $\boldsymbol c\in C$ of weight $w$ the code $C'$ will also contain the codeword $\boldsymbol c + \boldsymbol 1$ of weight $n-w$. Hence, you could apply the standard Brouwer-Zimmermann algorithm to the code $C'$. (The computer algebra system Magma contains an efficient implementation.) Each lower bound $b$ on the minimum weight of $C'$ will give an upper bound $n - b$ on the maximum weight of $C$.
The lower the minimum distance of $C$, the more useless this approach is...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! From the solutions I obtained with my randomized method, the very best I can do is around the 730s which makes me think the max weight is around 75% of $n$...
I will have a close look at your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of maximum-likelihood decoding, your problem is equivalent to decoding an all-ones received tuple (assuming a BSC with $p<1/2$, of course).

I don't know of any efficient general method for large dimensions. If the parity-check matrix is sparse (few ones), the approach of [LDPC codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-density_parity-check_code#Operational_use) (where "messages" are iteratively passed along "connected" nodes which represent the unknown codeword values, the received values and the parity-check equations) might interest you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used elementary row-operations to further sparsify the parity-check matrix (row operations don't change the null space, therefore solution set is the same, very convenient), and reduce the size of the Linear Program to solve it. These row operations alter the matrix 'form' since we have no more the guarantee of unit vectors in it, but the LDPC codes might help out here, thanks.
I also used a method that performs row operations to sparsify and preserve the unit vectors in the matrix to be able to exploit that property. I 'only' have to find a good solving method now.