# A modified lights out puzzle on a weighted graph

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following graph. Blue vertices are "switches" and red vertices are "lights" with certain weights which could be positive or negative. The states of the lights (red vertices) could be either "on" or "off". We are interested in a quantity, denoted as $w$, which is the sum of the weights of the lights that are "on".

The rule of changing the states of the lights: By selecting a blue vertex, the states of all neighboring lights are switched, and if a light is "on", it is switched to "off", and vice versa.

For instance, suppose all the lights are "off", then $w=0$ initially. Upon selecting the center blue vertex, the four neighboring lights are turned "on", with total weight $w=0.9+0.1+0.1-1=0.1$. If we select the center blue vertex again, then the four neighboring lights are switched "off", and it returns to $w=0$. On the other hand, if we select the center blue vertex, and the top center  blue vertex, we turn on five lights with total weight $w=0.9+0.1-1+1/2-3/4=-0.25$.

The above problem could be viewed as a modified [Lights out puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)), and one difference, among others, is that the lights carry different weights, and our objective is to find a way to minimize the total weights $w$.

In particular, if we start with all lights being "off" with $w=0$, I would like to device a general algorithm to find a set of selected blue vertices to minimize the weight. If this cannot be done exactly efficiently, an approximate method is also acceptable. We can assume the graph to be $N\times N$ [the one shown below can be thought as $3\times3$].

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The obvious approach would be to first determine for which sets $L$ of lights you can find an algorithm that leaves those lights on and all others off. If you can do that for any $L$, then let $L$ be the collection of all lights of negative weight, and your solution is the algorithm that turns those $L$ on. If not every set of lights can be turned on, then search for the minimal change that needs to be made to $L$ to make it obtainable.

Comment: If all weights are identical, this is the problem of finding a minimum weight codeword for a particular linear code over $GF(2)$, for which I believe there are subexponential-time algorithms.  I don't know whether any of them can be adapted to deal with different weights for the lights.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, given a configuration of lights (which ones are on and off), you can efficiently test whether that configuration is achievable, by solving a system of linear equations over $GF(2)$.  However, there are exponentially many such configurations, so your "search for the minimal change..." step can in general take exponential time.

Comment: @D.W. Could you point to me the references for the subexponential-time algorithms for the case with all the weights being identical? I am also interested in this case too. Thanks!

Comment: @fagd, see https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/120000/755.  I think if you search on Google Scholar you'll find dozens of papers on the subject.  I'm not sure which ones would be best to study first.  I'm not very knowledgeable on the subject.

Comment: @D.W. Yes, I can see that why the problem, when having identical weights, is equivalent to finding the distance of a linear code, and I found this answer which says the problem is hard (may be NP-complete if I got it right) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361046/minimum-distance-of-a-binary-linear-code/362039#362039. In any case, I will look at the one you attached, and search around. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $N_\ell$ be the set of switches that neighbor light $\ell$.  Let binary decision variable $x_s$ indicate whether switch $s$ is selected.  Let binary decision variable $y_\ell$ indicate whether light $\ell$ is on.  Let $z_\ell$ be a nonnegative integer decision variable.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_\ell w_\ell y_\ell$ subject to
$$\sum_{s\in N_\ell} x_s = 2z_\ell + y_\ell \quad \text{for all $\ell$}.$$
The idea is that light $\ell$ is on if and only if the number of selected neighbor switches is odd.

For your example, each light is associated with a pair of switches, so we can think of the switches as nodes and the lights as edges.  Here is SAS code to solve the problem, with the nodes numbered from left to right and top to bottom:

```
data EdgeData;
   input i j w;
   datalines;
1 2 0.5
1 4 0
2 3 -0.75
2 5 0.1
3 6 0
4 5 -1
4 7 -0.3
5 6 0.9
5 8 0.1
6 9 -0.8
7 8 -0.2
8 9 0.5
;

proc optmodel;
   set <num,num> EDGES;
   num w {EDGES};
   read data EdgeData into EDGES=[i j] w;
   set NODES = union {<i,j> in EDGES} {i,j};

   var X {NODES} binary;
   var Y {EDGES} binary;
   var Z {EDGES} >= 0 integer;
   min Objective = sum {<i,j> in EDGES} w[i,j] * Y[i,j];
   con C {<i,j> in EDGES}:
      sum {k in NODES: k in {i,j}} X[k] = 2 * Z[i,j] + Y[i,j];

   solve;
   print X;
   print Y Z;
quit;
```

The minimum turns out to be $-2.95$, achieved by taking $x_3=x_4=x_8=x_9=1$.  The $y$ and $z$ values are
\begin{matrix}
i &j &y_{ij} &z_{ij} \\
\hline 
1 &2 &0 &0 \\ 
1 &4 &1 &0 \\
2 &3 &1 &0 \\
2 &5 &0 &0 \\
3 &6 &1 &0 \\
4 &5 &1 &0 \\
4 &7 &1 &0 \\
5 &6 &0 &0 \\
5 &8 &1 &0 \\
6 &9 &1 &0 \\
7 &8 &1 &0 \\
8 &9 &0 &1
\end{matrix}

Comment: Thank you for writing out the formulation explicitly in terms of linear programing! This is precisely what I am looking for. A few follow up questions: a) Can we set $z_l$ arbitrarily, say $z_l=1$ or $z_l=2$? b) I am not familiar with linear programing. Do you have any reference or software on how to solve it? c) Can you comment on the complexity of solving the problem using linear programming? Thanks!

Comment: The solver determines $x$, $y$, and $z$ to minimize the objective.  I added SAS code to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful! I was able to rerun the same model with Julia [I am not familiar with SAS], and I got the answer x1=x2=x5=x6=x7=1, which is essentially the complement of the one you found. I will attach my code below in case it is useful for others. Many thanks again!

Comment: Hey @RobPratt, would you mind to comment on the complexity of the algorithm/code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer by @RobPratt. I attach the Julia code, which uses exactly the same model as the one by @RobPratt, in case it is useful. Reference: https://www.juliabloggers.com/optimization-with-jump-in-julia/

```
# Import pacakges: JuMP and GLPK 
using JuMP # Julia package - high level programming language
using GLPK # open-source solver - low level language

w = Dict(
    [1,2] => 0.5,
    [1,4] => 0.0,
    [2,3] => -0.75,
    [2,5] => 0.1,
    [3,6] => 0.0,
    [4,5] => -1,
    [4,7] => -0.3,
    [5,6] => 0.9,
    [5,8] => 0.1,
    [6,9] => -0.8,
    [7,8] => -0.2,
    [8,9] => 0.5
) ;

m = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)

# Declaring variables
@variable(m, X[1:9], Bin)
@variable(m, Y[1:9,1:9], Bin)
@variable(m, Z[1:9,1:9]>=0, Int) ; 

@objective(m, Min, sum([val * Y[key...] for (key, val) in w])) 

for (key, _) in w
    @constraint(m, Y[key...] + 2 * Z[key...] == sum(X[key]))
end
# println(m)

JuMP.optimize!(m)

println("X = ", JuMP.value.(X))

println("(i, j) Yij Zij")
for (key, _) in sort(w)
    println(key, " ", JuMP.value(Y[key...]), " ", JuMP.value(Z[key...]))
end
```

The output reads

```
X = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
(i, j) Yij Zij
[1, 2] 0.0 1.0
[1, 4] 1.0 0.0
[2, 3] 1.0 0.0
[2, 5] 0.0 1.0
[3, 6] 1.0 0.0
[4, 5] 1.0 0.0
[4, 7] 1.0 0.0
[5, 6] 0.0 1.0
[5, 8] 1.0 0.0
[6, 9] 1.0 0.0
[7, 8] 1.0 0.0
[8, 9] 0.0 0.0
```